# What is the difference between methods "insert subview" and "presentModalViewController"?

Tags: iphone, view

What is the difference between those two methods when it comes to changing the nib views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"insertsubview" retains the view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

"presentmodalviewcontroller" are tools that you can call without disrupting the current workflow and displaying a new set of views.

hope it will help you to understand in basic level and for more in depth please refer Apple's documentation of UIView and ViewControllers.

Comment: How do I know which obe to use?

Comment: I would rather suggest create a tab bar based application and bind your view controllers to the tab bar, so that you could easily navigate between your views.

Comment: I'm working on app which keeps score to one game, first screen is like a paper block which will display a score, but to add a score I want to call another view in which a user can type the score, and after he pushes Insert it will sum the score and display it on first screen

Comment: What is the best way to do this?

Comment: There are many ways you can implement your business requirement, but then looking at the scenario, best go with a modal view controller approach for your second/subsequent(score entry screen) view, where you can pass the values through properties to your base controller(paper block screen).

Answer (score 1):

The `addSubview:` method simply adds a new view to the view hierarchy, while `presentModalViewController:animated:` makes the given *view controller* the active view controller (and make its view visible).

Comment: So when I have 1 main view, and 5 views that I want to call from main view (settings in example), which method should I use?

Comment: @Wikiboo: If you have a dedicated view controller for your five views: `presentModalViewController:animated:`. Else you use `addSubview:`.

Comment: Just to make sure, dedicated view controller means that I have .h and .m for every nib, and they are connected to it, is that it?
I have mainControllerView which loads ApplicationControllerView on startup, and from that ApplicationControllerView I want to load 5 views (settings, statistics, and three more)
Sry if it's a noob question, I've juster started to work with multiple views

Comment: By *dedicated view controller* I mean you have a class (in a `.h` file) that derives from `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`. Yes, often you have a NIB file for these as well. Say, if you have a `SettingsViewController` you would push that with `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

Comment: And when I want to go back to ApplicationViewController I would push it back with dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:?

And can you please give me a link with example when to use addSubview, I'm finding hard to figure out what is the difference because in my head they have a same effect, and that is to show another view.

And I've just stumbled upon pushViewController in Apple documentation so I'm confused even more :D

Comment: @Wikiboo: I think it's about time you buy yourself a beginners iPhone development book. I don't think I can explain this to you well enough, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yep, just bought one book, and I'm reading about addSubview, but they did't mention presentModalViewController or pushViewController so I was curious :)